# Making a question into an answer

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Say that I have developed an original hack to work around some issue or other, but it looks quite ugly, so I ask Stack Overflow if there is a better or cleaner way to do this.

After a couple of days no-one offers any decent feedback, so can I make my question into "How do I work round this issue?" then copy my ugly hack into the answer, and mark it as accepted?

I think this would be OK, but I thought I'd just check.

Answer (score 2):

Questions are not required to have an answer - it is perfectly ok to keep question without an answer.

Instead of rewriting question (which is generally frowned upon) you can provide answer along the lines "as of 2016 there is no better solution. Following approaches don't work because ...".

Additionally you may want to consider bounty the question first if you interested in actual answer and not just showing off you clever code.

Answer (score 1):

Nominally it's frowned upon to edit your question drastically to avoid invaliding existing feedback, but if there is ***truly*** no feedback on the current state of the question ***and*** your edit does not radically deviate from what you originally asked, I don't have much of a qualm with this edit.

Of course, self-answering is encouraged, but it is held to the same standard as every other answer.